# How can I estimate if a feature is going to take up too many resources on an FPGA?

Tags: hardware, vhdl, fpga

I'm starting on my first commercial sized application, and I often find myself making a design, but stopping myself from coding and implementing it, because it seems like a huge use of resources. This is especially true when it's on a piece that is peripheral (for example an enable for the output taps of a shift register).  It gets even worse when I think about how large the generic implementation can get (4k bits for the taps example). The cleanest implementation would have these, but in my head it adds a great amount of overhead.

Is there any kind of rule I can use to make a quick decision on whether a design option is worth coding and evaluation?  In general I worry less about the number of flip-flops, and more when it comes to width of signals.  This may just be coming from a CS background where all application boundarys should be as small as possibly feasable to prevent overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 1. We learn by playing, so play! Try a couple of things. See what the tools do. Get a feel for the problem. You won't get past this is you don't try something. Often the problems aren't where you think they're going to be.

Point 2. You need to get some context for these decisions. How big is adding an enable to a shift register compared to the capacity of the FPGA / your design?

Point 3. There's two major types of 'resource' to consider :- Cells and Time.

Cells is relatively easy in broad terms. How many flops? How much logic in identifiable blocks (e.g. in an ALU: multipliers, adders, etc)? Often this is defined by the design you're trying to do. You can't build an ALU without registers, a multiplier, an adder, etc.

Time is more subtle, and is invariably traded off against cells. You'll be trying to hit some performance target and recognising the structures that will make that hard are where to experience from point 1 comes in.

Things to look out for include:

- A single net driving a large number of things. Large fan-outs cause a heavy load on a single driver which slows it down. The tool will then have to use cells to buffer that signal. Classic time vs cells trade off.
- Deep clumps of logic between register stages. Again the tool will have to spend more cells to make logic meet timing if it's close to the edge. Simple logic is fast and small. Sometimes introducing a pipeline stage can decrease the size of a design is it makes the logic either side far easier.

Don't worry so much about large buses, if each bit is low fanout and you've budgeted for the registers. Large buses are often inherent in fast designs because you need high bandwidth. It can be easier to go wide than to go to a higher clock speed. On the other hand, think about the control logic for a wide bus, because it's likely to have a large fan-out.

Different tools and target devices have different characteristics, so you have to play and learn the rules for your set-up. There's always a size vs speed (and these days 'vs power') compromise. You need to understand what moves you along that curve in each direction. That comes with experience.

> Is there any kind of rule I can use to make a quick decision on whether a design option is worth coding and evaluation?

Only rule I can come up with is 'Have I got time? or not?'

If I have, I'll explore. If not I better just make **something** work.

Ahhh, the life of doing design to a deadline!

Answer (score 1):

It's something that comes with experience.  Here's some pointers:

- adding numbers is fairly cheap
- choosing between them (multiplexing) gets big quite quickly if you have a lot of inputs to the multiplexer (the width of each input is a secondary issue also).
- Multiplications are free if you have spare multipliers in your chip, they suddenly become expensive when you run out of hard DSP blocks.
- memory is also cheap, until you run out.  For example, your 4Kbit shift register easily fits within a single Xilinx block RAM, which is fine if you have one to spare.  If not it'll take a large number of LUTs (depending on the device - an older Spartan 3 can fit 17 bits into a LUT (including the in-CLB register), so will require ~235 LUTS).  And not all LUTs can *be* shift registers.  If you are only worried about the enable for the register, don't.  Unless you are pushing the performance of the device, routing that sort of signal to a few hundred LUTs is unlikely to cause major timing issues.